# ElasticSearch : IN equivalent operator in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find ElasticSearch query equivalent to `IN` \ `NOT` in SQL.

I know we can use QueryString query with multiple OR to get the same answer, but that ends up with lot of OR's.

Can anyone share the example?

Comment: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Similar to what Chris suggested as a comment, the analogous replacement for `IN` is the [`terms` *filter*](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) (queries imply scoring, which may improve the returned order).

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

The equivalent Elasticsearch 1.x filter would be:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The equivalent Elasticsearch 2.x+ filter would be:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The important takeaway is that the `terms` filter (and query for that matter) work on exact matches. It is implicitly an `or` operation, similar to `IN`.

If you wanted to invert it, you could use the not filter, but I would suggest using the slightly more verbose `bool`/`must_not` filter (to get in the habit of also using `bool`/`must` and `bool`).

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "terms" : {
          "id" : [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Overall, the `bool` compound query syntax is [one of the most important filters in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), as are the `term` (singular) and `terms` filters (plural, as shown).

Comment: what will be the time complexity for above query if array size is 800 or more

Comment: what is the limitations here. any maximum array size?

Comment: Is it possible to provide another query instead of string array?

Comment: Ultimately, the complexity of providing an array of size N means iterating over N terms and including / excluding the docs with those terms in the inverted index. In terms of the other query, you probably are looking for `bool`/`should` (and `"minimum_should_match": 1`) to get `OR` behavior of separate queries.

Answer (score 6):

1  **terms**

you can use **terms** term query in ElasticSearch that will act as IN

terms query is used to check if the value matches any of the provided values from **Array**.

2  **must_not**

**must_not** can be used as NOT in ElasticSearch.

ex.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query" : {
         "bool" : {
              "must":[
                {
                   "terms": {
                        "id" : ["1234","12345","123456"]
                    }
                },
                {
                   "bool" : {
                        "must_not" : [
                            {
                              "match":{
                                  "id" : "123"
                               }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
              ]
         }
    }
}
```

3. **exists**

Also if it helps you can also use **"exists"** query to check if the field exists or not.
for ex,
check if the field exists

```
"exists" : {
      "field" : "mobileNumber"
   }
```

check if a field does not exist

```
"bool":{
    "must_not" : [
        {
           "exists" : {
               "field" : "mobileNumber"
           }
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I saw what you requested.
And I wrote the source code as below.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

sql query :

```
select * from tablename where fieldname in ('AA','BB');
```

elastic search :

```
{
    query :{
        bool:{
            must:[{
              "script": {
                "script":{
                  "inline": "(doc['fieldname'].value.toString().substring(0,2).toUpperCase() in ['AA','BB']) == true"
                }
              }
            }],
            should:[],
            must_not:[]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First: there are easier ways to do a "startsWith" style string in ES and Java/Painless for that matter. Second: this is not equivalent to the SQL query. My original answer is still correct here.