# ElasticSearch : IN operator query with query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to match records against a query string, so I wrote the following query which is working fine:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["rollno","name"],
        "query": "*John*"
      }
  }
}
```

Now, apart from matching the `fields`, I want to implement `IN` query against another field as well. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114975/3913366) query, as:

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "fields": ["rollno", "name"],
        "query": "*John*"
    },
    "match": {
        "majorSubject": ["Biology", "Chemistry"]
    }
  }
}
```

All I get is `search_parse_exception`.

How to this `IN` operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `bool/must` query in order to combine both sub-queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "rollno",
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "*John*"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "majorSubject": [
              "Biology",
              "Chemistry"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if the `majorSubject` field is an analyzed string, use lowercase terms instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "rollno",
              "name"
            ],
            "query": "*John*"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "majorSubject": [
              "biology",
              "chemistry"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, query doesn't return any results at all, when I actually have matching data. Please see my answer how I solved this. That may have side-affects I do not know right now.

Comment: Try with lowercase `biology` and `chemistry`

Comment: Yes, that's because the `majorSubject` field is an analyzed string and henced the indexed tokens were lowercased.

Comment: I understand. When I defined my mapping, I should have specified `majorSubject ` as `non_analyzed` so that only exact values are matched against it as in my case, `majorSubject ` will have some fixed values only. But right now, `anatomy` will match both `Social anatomy` and `Biological anatomy`, definitely a problem. Thanks for the insight !