# Elastic Search: filter query results by entry its field into another query results

Tags: elasticsearch

I found the question about the IN equivalent operator:

[ElasticSearch : IN equivalent operator in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111258/elasticsearch-in-equivalent-operator-in-elasticsearch)

But I would to find equivalent to the another more complicated request:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM anotherTable WHERE something > 0);
```

Mapping:

First index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "products": { 
      "properties": { 
        "id":      { "type": "integer" },  
        "name":    { "type": "text"  }, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "reserved": { 
      "properties": { 
        "id":      { "type": "integer" },  
        "type":    { "type": "text"  }, 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get products which ids are contained in reserved index and have the specific type of a reserve.

Comment: Please provide your mapping and some document example

Comment: I added the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First step** - get all relevant ids from `reserved` index:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "TYPE_HERE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

--> see: [Terms Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), [Bool Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-term-query.html).

--> `_source` will retrieve only relevant field `id`.

**Second step** - get all relevant documents from `products` index:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "id": [
              "ID_1",
              "ID_2",
              "AND_SO_ON..."
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

--> take all the ids from first step and put them as a list under `terms:id[...]`

--> see [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-terms-query.html).

Comment: Alas, the body of the second request will be enormous. Anyway, thank you  for your answer!

Comment: You can split the list and use several queries OR query one by one