# Elastica : IN equivalent operator in Elastica

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

Following [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111258/elasticsearch-in-equivalent-operator-in-elasticsearch), I'm trying to do the same but with the [PHP Elastica](http://elastica.io/) and I wasn't successful doing it.

I am trying to give my `new \Elastica\Query\Terms` an array and I can't find the right way to do so.

I've tried doing it this way :

```
new \Elastica\Query\Terms(array($grp_field_p => array('value' => $array_pids)))
```

Where `$array_pids` is an array containing multiple ids :

```
array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    ...
    23015
);
```

The term aggregation is expecting a `$key => $value` and the `$value` can't be an array, if it's not a number he gives me an error.

> [terms] query does not support [null]]

The question is, how to correctly pass to the terms aggregation an array instead of a number to simulate an `SQL : IN` ?

Comment: Can you add the complete error you get?

Comment: @Val I'm sorry I didn't copy the proper part of the error that is useful.

Comment: Ok then your `$array_pids` seems to be null in that case, which the `terms` query doesn't like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on its [source code](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/86b2ed9fd99d3990d330bcb48e08afd5bce5365f/lib/Elastica/Query/Terms.php#L36) :

```
public function __construct($key = '', array $terms = [])
{
    $this->setTerms($key, $terms);
}
```

it should work like this:

```
new Elastica\Query\Terms($grp_field_p, $array_pids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$terms = new Elastica\Query\Terms();       
$terms->setTerms($grp_field_p, $array_pids);
```

Comment: I do get a [`TooManyClauses[maxClauseCount is set to 1024]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275514/elasticsearch-set-max-clause-count) error but I suppose that's another problem, thanks!